# Перенаправление ввода\вывода

Tags: c#, mono, gdb, redirect, linux

Использую gdb для получения некой отладочной информации в программе.

[image]

Ввожу в терминал "gdb gs", потом идёт некая обработка. Когда обработка завершена вылазит (gdb), мол ждём, можно вводить команду дальше.

Есть код:

```
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = "gdb";
    psi.Arguments = "gs";
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;

    Process p = Process.Start(psi);
    while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        string _out = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(_out);

        if (обработка завершена)
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("info variables");
    }
```

В цикле while идёт чтение каждой новой строки по мере поступления, последняя строка "...done." Дальше никаких новых строк я не получаю, нету строки "(gdb)", так и продолжается ожидание в цикле. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как понять когда завершилась обработка. Можно проверять конец строки, если "done.", то продолжать, но это не подходит. Надо получить событие появления "(gdb)".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. GDB не завершается, он так и висит и ждёт внутренних команд, процесс остается. А проблема была решена тем, что вместо ReadLine() использовал Read() (посимвольно), а (gdb) не читало, потому что это еще не была завершена строка, а по символам было видно.

Answer (score 1):

Если Я правильно Вас понял, то нужно отловить событие завершения выполнения "gdb". В таком случае включаем EnableRaisingEvent и вешаем EventHandler на Exited.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class ProcessClass
{
    public ProcessClass()
    {
        this.ProcessToExec = new Process();
    }

    private Process ProcessToExec
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    private bool EventHandled
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // Print a file with any known extension. 
    public void Execute(string fileName, string args)
    {
        this.EventHandled = false;

        try
        {
            // Start a process to print a file and raise an event when done.
            this.ProcessToExec.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
            this.ProcessToExec.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            this.ProcessToExec.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            this.ProcessToExec.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            this.ProcessToExec.StartInfo.UseShellExecute=true;
            this.ProcessToExec.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            this.ProcessToExec.Exited += new EventHandler(processToExec_Exited);
            this.ProcessToExec.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred trying to execute \"{0}\":" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, fileName);
            return;
        }

        // Wait for Exited event
        while (!this.EventHandled)
        {
            string _out = this.ProcessToExec.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(_out);           
        }
        this.ProcessToExec.StandardInput.WriteLine("info variables");
    }

    // Handle Exited event
    private void processToExec_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        this.EventHandled = true;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a file name.");
            return;
        }

        // Create the process
        ProcessClass myProcess = new ProcessClass();
        myProcess.Execute(args[0], (args.Length==2 ? args[1]:string.Empty));
    }
}
```